# lower bound for probability distribution of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

If $X$ is a random variable with finite mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, how do I show that the estimate

\begin{equation*}
P[\mu − d\sigma < X < \mu + d\sigma] ≥ 1 − 1/d^2~\forall d>1
\end{equation*}

holds? I found this in a book but unable to see the proof. Note that $X$ may not be normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality), which holds for any probability distribution.  There are two proofs given on the linked Wikipedia page - a measure-theoretic one, and one that uses [Markov's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality).

Your expression is in a different form, though, than the one on the Wikipedia page.  To see how they are the same, observe that

$$P[\mu - d \sigma < X < \mu + d \sigma] \geq 1 - 1/d^2$$
is equivalent to
$$P[|X - \mu| < d \sigma] \geq 1 - 1/d^2,$$
which is equivalent to
$$P[|X - \mu| > d \sigma] \leq 1/d^2,$$

which is the one on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: "which holds for any probability distribution" - this is only true of distributions whose variance is defined.